# Comparing array from user to array from database PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on adding product module.

The user can upload a csv file to add products. How can I create a system that  if there is existing product in db, it will skip the product and then check again for another product. If there is no such product in the db, then the product will be added into the db.

So let's say

```
//Products in db 
//Code       //Description
1            Item 1
2            Item 2
3            Item 3

//Products in user input
//Code       //Description
1            Item 1 
3            Item 3
4            Item 4
5            Item 5
```

From above example, how can I create a system that will add only Item 4 and Item 5 into the db?

Here is my $db_products array that contains products from db

```
foreach($db_products as $prod){
  $products[] = array(
    "code" => $prod['code'],
    "description" => $prod['description']
  );
}
```

Here is my $products_array which contains user input

```
foreach($products as $v){
    $products_array[] = array(
        "code"        => $v['code'],
        "description" => $v['description'],
    );
}
```

I used this code to compare

```
foreach($products_array as $prod){
  foreach($db_products as $db_prod){
    $result = array_diff($db_prod, $prod);
        var_dump($result);
  }
}
```

But why it returns me the same data between the arrays?

What am I missing here?? thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php. just take the difference. please take care that your csv array will be first array in this function argument. thanks  example:-https://eval.in/630846

Comment: What if a few people add 1 million products at the same time... with malformed data additionally, your server is going to detonate.
Think of the criteria which identifies a product and how to keep the server chilled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to check if `$prod` from `$products_array` exists in the multidimensional array `$db_products`, like this:

```
$products_to_add = array();
foreach ($products_array as $prod) {
    if (!inMultiArray($prod, $db_products)) {
        $products_to_add[] = $prod; // Add the product that's -not- in the DB to $products_to_add
    }
}

function inMultiArray($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (is_object($item)) {
            $item = get_object_vars($item);
        }

        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && inMultiArray($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```